# Transforming data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Transform is deprecated in Elasticsearch 2.0. In the elasticsearch docs it's mentioned that "As of now there really isn’t a feature to use in its place other than transforming the document in the client application." Could you elaborate on this sentence please. What exactly do they mean by transforming in client application?

This is the link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html

Comment: Truly sad that they've deprecated this.  There is data that only exists on elasticsearch, so it's impossible to transform it on the client.

Answer (score 1):

It means that instead of modifying the source fields when indexing in Elastic using the transform script, you should create the final json in your application and send it to Elastic for indexing.

Instead of having this mapping:

```
{
    "example" : {
        "transform" : {
            "script" : {
                "inline": "if (ctx._source['title']?.startsWith('t')) ctx._source['suggest'] = ctx._source['content']",
                "params" : {
                    "variable" : "not used but an example anyway"
                },
                "lang": "groovy"
            }
        },
        "properties": {
           "title": { "type": "string" },
           "content": { "type": "string" },
           "suggest": { "type": "string" }
        }
    }
}
```

You will just use this one:

```
{
    "example" : {
        "properties": {
           "title": { "type": "string" },
           "content": { "type": "string" },
           "suggest": { "type": "string" }
        }
    }
}
```

And construct the jsons in your application while enforcing the transform rules. In my example it would mean making the field "suggest" of the json body equal to the value in "content" if the title starts with a 't'.